# "Quick Views" in Microsoft Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Windows Live Mail for email and I have around 10 different e-mail addresses of various types but mainly POP3. WLM has "Quick Views" that amalgamate all the different email from all my sources together. They are called All Inbox, Unread, Unread from contacts, etc. I use the Quick Views primarily, but I also want to keep the emails in their original mailboxes as well.

I cannot see an equivalent in Outlook 2013, the nearest I can find is something to copy them all into one giant Inbox, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way. You can only create Search Folders inside the one particular storage/mailbox. There is no way to aggregate data from multiple mailboxes.